# XSLT: iteration on string with indexes

Tags: xslt, indexing, split, iteration

I am having a trouble with very easy XSLT transformation. Let's assume that this is the input XML document:

```
<root>
  <myString>ABBCD</myString>
</root>
```

The output XML should be:

```
<root>
    <myCharacters>
        <character>
            <id>1</id>
            <value>A</value>
        </character>
        <character>
            <id>2</id>
            <value>B</value>
        </character>
        <character>
            <id>3</id>
            <value>B</value>
        </character>
        <character>
            <id>4</id>
            <value>C</value>
        </character>
        <character>
            <id>5</id>
            <value>D</value>
        </character>
    </myCharacters>
</root>
```

Is there an easy way to split such string and increment index over it?

Comment: One easy way would be to do a VBscript function call inb your xslt which will take the value and return the set of nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy in XSLT 2.0...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <myString>ABBCD</myString>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myString">
        <myCharacters>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=".">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <character>
                    <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
                </character>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
        </myCharacters>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <myCharacters>
      <character>
         <id>1</id>
         <value>A</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>2</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>3</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>4</id>
         <value>C</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>5</id>
         <value>D</value>
      </character>
   </myCharacters>
</root>
```

It's not terrible in 1.0 either. You can use a recursive template. The following will produce the same output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myString">
        <myCharacters>
            <xsl:call-template name="analyzeString">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </myCharacters>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="analyzeString">
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <character>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="$pos"/></id>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="substring($string,1,1)"/></value>
        </character>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($string)>=2">
            <xsl:call-template name="analyzeString">
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos+1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 (you posted pretty much exactly the XSLT 1.0 solution I was working on a few seconds before I finished writing it ;-)

Comment: @IanRoberts - Thank you. I knew someone would have a 1.0 answer fast, so I did the 2.0 answer first. I just got lucky getting the 1.0 answer in too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**I. XSLT 1.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vStyle" select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:template match="myString">
  <xsl:variable name="vStr" select="."/>
  <root>
    <myCharacters>
      <xsl:for-each select=
      "($vStyle//node()|$vStyle//@*|$vStyle//namespace::*)
                      [not(position() > string-length($vStr))]">

        <character>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="substring($vStr,position(),1)"/></value>
        </character>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </myCharacters>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
  <myString>ABBCD</myString>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  <root>
   <myCharacters>
      <character>
         <id>1</id>
         <value>A</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>2</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>3</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>4</id>
         <value>C</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>5</id>
         <value>D</value>
      </character>
   </myCharacters>
</root>
```

**Alternatively, with FXSL one can use the `str-map` template like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:testmap="testmap" xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext testmap">
   <xsl:import href="str-dvc-map.xsl"/>
   <testmap:testmap/>
   <xsl:variable name="vTestMap" select="document('')/*/testmap:*[1]"/>

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="myString">
    <xsl:variable name="vrtfChars">
     <xsl:call-template name="str-map">
       <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vTestMap"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="."/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <myCharacters>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfChars)/*"/>
    </myCharacters>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="enumChars" match="*[namespace-uri() = 'testmap']"
    mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
        <character>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/></value>
        </character>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="character">
     <character>
       <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </character>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**to produce the same correct result**:

```
  <myCharacters>
   <character>
      <id>1</id>
      <value>A</value>
   </character>
   <character>
      <id>2</id>
      <value>B</value>
   </character>
   <character>
      <id>3</id>
      <value>B</value>
   </character>
   <character>
      <id>4</id>
      <value>C</value>
   </character>
   <character>
      <id>5</id>
      <value>D</value>
   </character>
</myCharacters>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution -- shorter and simpler than other answers:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="myString">
  <root>
    <myCharacters>
      <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints(.)">
        <character>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/></value>
        </character>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </myCharacters>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  <root>
   <myCharacters>
      <character>
         <id>1</id>
         <value>A</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>2</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>3</id>
         <value>B</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>4</id>
         <value>C</value>
      </character>
      <character>
         <id>5</id>
         <value>D</value>
      </character>
   </myCharacters>
</root>
```